# How to handle onClick event on imageSpan in editText?

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannable, imagespan

i am working on an app in which user choose an image from gallery and it will be added in editText, now i want if user click on image in editText it should open in fullScreen, i used below code :-

```
public void addToEdt(Bitmap bitmap){
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString("abc");
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    edt_note.setTransformationMethod(null);
    edt_note.getText().insert(edt_note.getSelectionStart(), ss);

    final int start = ss.getSpanStart(span);
    final int end = ss.getSpanEnd(span);

    ClickableSpan click_span = new ClickableSpan() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };

    ClickableSpan[] click_spans = ss.getSpans(start, end,  ClickableSpan.class);

    if(click_spans.length != 0) {
        // remove all click spans
        for (ClickableSpan c_span : click_spans) {
            ss.removeSpan(c_span);
        }
    }

    ss.setSpan(click_span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

tried above code but its not listening onClick event,
now, how can i listen click event on this image and do further task?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Clickable Span at the same start and end locations of the editText.

```
sb.setSpan(cs, imageStartSpan,imageEndSpan , Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Also

```
editText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I cannot write the whole code for you. Try the below sample:-

```
public void addToEdt(Bitmap bitmap){
    SpannableString ss = new SpannableString();
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
    ss.append("abc"); // Append the text here
    ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
    ss.setSpan(span, 0, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); // start(0) and end (2) will create an image span over abc text
    ss.setSpan(new ClickableSpan() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View widget) {
                    ss.delete(0, 2);
                    editText.setText(ss);
                }
            },0, 2, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE); // this will add a clickable span and on click will delete the span and text
    editText.setText(ss); // this will show your image/clickable span in edittext
}


editText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: i tried setMovementMethod but its not working, will you please explain in detail, where should i change in my ABOVE code( addToEdt(Bitmap bitmap) method)

Comment: ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(d, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BASELINE);
ss.setSpan(span, 0, 3, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);  Same way add clickablespan to same location start and end --> 0,3.

Comment: sorry i dont get, can you edit my code and post as your answer , if its working i will accept your answer :)

Comment: Thanks alottttttttt man you made my day :), just one issue , by calling setMovementMethod , cursor of editText gone :o , now it looks odd, have any trick for this???

Comment: hey rahul, why you delete span and text using ss.delete(0, 2);.......is there any specific purpose or its just for demo???

Comment: It will delete the data from SpannableString and to reflect the same in Edittext, you can pass it to EditText.

Comment: a repeat of the previous question - What happens if you don't delete the span?

Answer (score 5):

I did not find using `ClickableSpan` and `setMovementMethod` to be acceptable given the problems it causes. I do not believe these were intended to be used in EditText control.

Also, I need to know WHERE the user clicked in the span. My image span has an X close button at the right side and I want to know if the user clicked on the X as opposed to just clicking on the label.

So I found another way:

- Subclass `ImageSpan` and override the `draw` method to just call the super, but also to store the x/y/left/top in member variables - so, now you know where the span is positioned inside the EditText.
- Subclass `EditText` and handle `onTouchEvent` to just call the super, but also get your spans and hit test each one to find out if the user tapped on the span (or a part of the span).

That's it, this method works with no side effects.

Comment: Haw you can get Y of X-close button? It should be change when edittext scroll, but I have const

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
final int start = ss.getSpanStart(span);
final int end = ss.getSpanEnd(span);

ClickableSpan click_span = new ClickableSpan() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View widget) {

    }
};

ClickableSpan[] click_spans = ss.getSpans(start, end, ClickableSpan.class);

if(click_spans.length != 0) {
    // remove all click spans
    for (ClickableSpan c_span : click_spans) {
        ss.removeSpan(c_span);
    }
}

ss.setSpan(click_span, start, end, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
```

Also add this:

```
yourEditText.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Thanks, just trying out your code then will give you feedback :)

Comment: not working, fire a toast onClick but not listening to click event :(

Comment: @Nishusharma Take a look again please. Add the last line

Comment: i added setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance()) to editText then it gives error when  calling addToEdt(Bitmap bitmap); .......means after adding setMovementMethod i am not able even to add image :(

Comment: Hmm Take a look to these posts: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16182500/2528167 http://stackoverflow.com/a/6357661/2528167

Comment: had seen but didnt found solution :( stackoverflow was the only hope for me ;(

Comment: Let someone else post his answer @Nishusharma

Comment: yeah, hope so....else i have to use imageView for this....although your answer didnt sort out the problem but still you tried to help me so i accepting your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution that is less intrusive than going with `LinkMovementMethod`. Instead, I simply extended `ArrowKeyMovementMethod` (the default movement method for `EditText`) and added some of the code from `LinkMovementMethod` that is used to determine the span that was clicked. In my case I looked for an `ImageSpan` and then deleted the text that span covered (so a click removes the image):

```
private class SpanDeletingMovementMethod : ArrowKeyMovementMethod() {
    override fun onTouchEvent(
        widget: TextView,
        buffer: Spannable,
        event: MotionEvent
    ): Boolean {
        if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            var x = event.x.toInt()
            var y = event.y.toInt()
            x -= widget.totalPaddingLeft
            y -= widget.totalPaddingTop
            x += widget.scrollX
            y += widget.scrollY
            val layout = widget.layout
            val line = layout.getLineForVertical(y)
            val off = layout.getOffsetForHorizontal(line, x.toFloat())

            val committedTags = buffer.getSpans<ImageSpan>(off, off)
            if (committedTags.isNotEmpty()) {
                val tag = committedTags[0]
                (buffer as Editable).replace(buffer.getSpanStart(tag), buffer.getSpanEnd(tag), "")
                return true
            }
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(widget, buffer, event)
    }
}
```

simply set this movement method on the `EditText` (or override `getDefaultMovementMethod`), and you can handle span clicks.